# ng-repeat in template page shows no data

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to learn angular and I am stuck trying to repeat a div from a json object.  I have confirmed that the json object is being returned,  if I just put the paragraph tags display myData correctly but my div is not repeating or even showing when I inspect the html in review.html.  According to jsonlint my json is valid as well.  Any idea what could be wrong here?

Here is index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>All The Reviews</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.3/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="myScript.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="homeController">
 <div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation" style="padding-left:130px;">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#/">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#/reviews">Reviews</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/create">Create</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </div>
<br/>
  <div ng-view class="jumbotron"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my template reviews.html

```
<div style="padding-left:130px;padding-right:200px;">
 <h1>Reviews</h1>
 <p>{{myData}}</p>
 <div ng-repeat="review in myData.reviews">{{review.title}}</div>
</div>
```

Here is my js file

```
var app=angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);


app.config(function($routeProvider){


  $routeProvider
      .when('/',{
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: 'homeController'
      })
      .when('/reviews',{
            templateUrl: 'reviews.html',
            controller: 'reviewsController'
      });


});


app.controller('homeController',function($scope, $http){

});

app.controller('reviewsController',function($scope, $http){

 $scope.myData={};

 $http.get('myData.json').success(function(data) {
  $scope.myData = data;
 });

});
```

And here is my json data

```
[{"products":[{"productId":"1","name":"Fluffy Eggs"},{"productId":"1","name":"Crispy Bacon"}]},
{"reviews":[{"reviewId":"1","title":"These are some nice eggs.","productId":"1","description":"Eggs that are just the right temp and extremely fluffy."},
{"reviewId":"2","title":"mmm, bacon","productId":"2","description":"it's pretty crispy. Maybe a little too crispy."}]},
{"ratings":[{"ratingId":"1","reviewId":"1","rating":"5"},
{"ratingId":"2","reviewId":"1","rating":"4"},
{"ratingId":"3","reviewId":"2","rating":"1"},
{"ratingId":"4","reviewId":"1","rating":"5"},
{"ratingId":"5","reviewId":"1","rating":"5"},
{"ratingId":"6","reviewId":"2","rating":"5"},
{"ratingId":"7","reviewId":"2","rating":"4"},
{"ratingId":"8","reviewId":"1","rating":"5"}]}]
```

Thanks for all your input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON structure is an array containing the three objects with the properties *products*, *reviews* and *ratings*. Therefore you have to select the second item to loop over your reviews:

```
<div ng-repeat="review in myData[1].reviews">{{review.title}}</div>
```

[See this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GYKg6WTsyzU04RbTjex3?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Change your json to:

```
{"products":[{"productId":"1","name":"Fluffy Eggs"},{"productId":"1","name":"Crispy Bacon"}],
"reviews":[{"reviewId":"1","title":"These are some nice eggs.","productId":"1","description":"Eggs that are just the right temp and extremely fluffy."},
{"reviewId":"2","title":"mmm, bacon","productId":"2","description":"it's pretty crispy. Maybe a little too crispy."}],
"ratings":[{"ratingId":"1","reviewId":"1","rating":"5"},
{"ratingId":"2","reviewId":"1","rating":"4"},
{"ratingId":"3","reviewId":"2","rating":"1"},
{"ratingId":"4","reviewId":"1","rating":"5"},
{"ratingId":"5","reviewId":"1","rating":"5"},
{"ratingId":"6","reviewId":"2","rating":"5"},
{"ratingId":"7","reviewId":"2","rating":"4"},
{"ratingId":"8","reviewId":"1","rating":"5"}]}
```

Comment: I tried this as well, but I got an error about a non whitespace character or somethings.  thanks